# When server block requests from mine website?

Tags: php, request

I know that websites are protect from bots by controlling the ip. 
Who connects to my website start a request to another website and each has the own ip, then the website see multiple ip for each request.
I want to know if there a risk that the website block my requests seeing that those ip start request from the same site every time.
Instead of blocking requests from an IP, is possible that they block requests from my website?
My requests is in php.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Depends on following things:

- How often does this request happen?
- What service does the other site provide?
- Do they allow data requests by bots?

Every website hoster can adjust the limit manually. There is no "YES you will be blocked" or "NO you wont". For example google lets you make 2500 API Requests an hour. Other sites i know let you do 10,000. So it depends on the hoster